# Using Checker Framework in Eclipse Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, checker-framework

I'd like to use the Checker Framework using their [Eclipse Plugin](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/checker-plugin/update-site/). This seems to work fine if I have a single project without dependencies.

However, when I try to run the check on my maven projects, I get hundreds of warnings, saying:

`cannot find symbol`

In the console I get the following Report:

`"MainActivity.java:33: error: package de.my.dependency does not exist
import de.my.dependency;"`

I assume that the Eclipse Checker plugin cannot resolve the maven dependencies, is there anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mind taking a moment and adding any relevant details about your project setup to the following issue:  [checker-framework-185](http://code.google.com/p/checker-framework/issues/detail?id=185)

Specifically, are you using m2eclipse?  And is there anything peculiar about your setup?

Sorry for the delay in responding.  In the future the best way to get help for the Checker Framework would be to either post in the checker framework discussion group [checker-framework-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/checker-framework-discuss) or, if you think we have a bug or an obviously missing feature, please create an issue in our google code issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed and should work with the latest Checker Framework release.